# Did NASA have a simulator to practice the moon landings?

Tags: moon

https://www.nasa.gov/centers/langley/multimedia/road2apollo-16.html

> With floodlights shining down to simulate lunar light and the base modeled to resemble the lunar surface, 24 astronauts practiced landing at the Lunar Landing Research Facility at NASA Langley Research Center.
>
> Suspended from the facility at one-sixth the Earth's gravity, the Lunar Excursion Module Simulator (LEMS) enabled astronauts to practice landing on the lunar surface.

This question is NOT asking whether the moon landings are a hoax or not. It is specifically asking whether such a simulator was constructed to resemble the lunar surface.

Comment: If NASA's claim is false, I'm going to have a headache trying to comprehend things.

Comment: How can anyone answer your question?  If you won't accept a photograph and description on the NASA website, what would convince you?

Comment: -1, since this question doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @nat it's an interesting piece of trivia, one that I hadn't heard even though there've been umpteen conspiracy theorists about the landings.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yeah, I definitely agree that the topic's interesting.  Just, the interesting aspects of the topic are off-topic here; they'd be more appropriate for [SE.SpaceExploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There were a number of different simulators, for instance the LLTV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Landing_Research_Vehicle which was an actual flying vehicle with thrusters that automatically cancelled out 5/6 of Earth's gravity, giving a realistic landing experience.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

[From the National Park Service](https://www.nps.gov/parkhistory/online_books/butowsky4/space14.htm):

> The Lunar Landing Research Facility is in the West Area of the Langley
>   Research Center. This facility was constructed in 1965 at a cost of
>   $3.5 million and was used by the Apollo astronauts as a training
>   simulator to study and practice piloting problems in the final phase
>   of the lunar landing mission.

The primary structure at the facility was apparently a 250-foot-high, 400-foot-long gantry with a hoist system which allowed researchers and test pilots to develop mechanisms and techniques for maneuvering mock lunar landers to a simulated lunar surface. Here's a scan of what the owner [describes as a contemporaneous photo](http://stellar-views.com/Photos_Apollo_P1.html) of the gantry and hoist, featuring one of several landers tested at the site.
[image: mock lunar lander held aloft by a hoist]

> The base of the Lunar Landing Facility was modeled with fill dirt to
>   resemble the surface of the Moon. Pock-marked holes, pits and craters
>   resemble the lunar landscape encountered by Apollo 11 when it landed
>   on the Moon in July 1969.

[Here is a PDF](https://crgis.ndc.nasa.gov/crgis/images/a/a0/LARC1970.pdf) of the Jan. 9, 1970 Langley Researcher newsletter where the site is discussed.

Here is a [2009 photo of the gantry taken by a Flickr user](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bluemiataman/3185427759/in/photolist-qEoazL-fqAUMf-8pyo5H-qQU7CJ-pVSiGL-in99j1-qUEKtE-in9mMr-q1bdRc-in9k3V-in8FKu-in9qu6-GWbq9s-6r13Uo-d75YXb-mLYhgM-incr4P-indwHk-ind47P-fAWrXp-incuzh-9LfzAW-incKv7-qWTih9-incYfq-ozv7Nd-bh523a-5Ru9Gg-dcucUP-qPywnL-fstmZg-fstntk-MHkUtJ-fsHH9U-KJimLE).

Here is a current aerial view of the gantry from Google Maps at N 37° 06.065 W 076° 23.344: [image: red and white gantry, aerial view]

And the view from Google Street View (dated June 2016):[image: view of gantry past trees and buildings]